# jquery - xeditable select source using function, using deffered and local storage (indexedDB)

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, jquery-deferred, x-editable

I am working on a web app for the company that I work for and I have a problem with a form that is required.

I'm having a bit of trouble populating a select list with data from a different function using xeditable.

The problem is the code that is being executed to populate the select box doesn't wait for the other function to get data from local storage and return it, even though I am using deffered, (I'm not sure if I am using the deffered/resolve functionality correctly).

This is the code that I have:

```
<a id="TypeID" data-type="select" data-pk="1966_TypeID" data-original-title="Please Select" data-pid="36" class="editable editable-click">3609</a>
```

jquery:

```
function popSelectBox(PID) {
    var rtn = [];
    $.indexedDB('testDatabase').objectStore('Lookup').index('PID').each(function (i) {
        var source = {};
        source.value = i.value.ID;
        source.text = i.value.Name;
        rtn.push(source);
    }, PID).done(function (r, e) {
        console.log(rtn);
        console.log('popSelectBox function (I expect to see this first) - This section should complete before the makeEditable function');

        return rtn;
    });
}

function makeEditable() {
    $('.editable').editable({
        validate: function (value) {
            if ($.trim(value) === '') {
                return 'This field is required';
            }
            return false;
        },
        success: function (response, newValue) {
            console.log($(this).data('pk'), newValue);
            //$(this).parent().css('background-color', 'green');
        },
        /**** this is the problem section of this function ****/
        source: function () {
            //if the type is a select list then we need to populate it, this is done here
            if ($(this).data('type') === 'select') {
                var d = $.Deferred();
                $.when(d).done(function (v) {
                    console.log(v);
                    return v;
                });
                d.resolve(popSelectBox($(this).data('pid').toString()));
                console.log('makeEditable function (I expect to see this last) - This section should wait for the popSelectBox function to finish');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I also have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/f8otrayn/3/ that shows the above.
Included in this fiddle is an example local storage set up that I am using, the functions to set this up are present, however I have commented out the function call, you can check the code and uncomment if you wish.

I am looking for a way to wait until the popSelectBox function has finished and returned data so I can use that data to populate the select box, I don't really want to use setTimeout as there are lots of entries in local storage so waiting a specific period of time may not work in all instances.

Does anyone have any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end we have had to go down a different route and rather than add the functionality when initially building the form, we have added the functionality to a click event

x-editable still wasn't able to populate the source from a function so as suggested ran the code (in scope) to get the correct values from IndexedDB before and added the results array as the source

code below for reference

```
$( document ).on('click', '.editable-select', function(){
    var arr = [];
    $.indexedDB( 'testDatabase' ).objectStore( 'Lookup' ).index( 'PID' ).each( function( i ) {
        if (i.value.Act === '1') {
            arr.push({
                value: i.value.ID,
                text:i.value.Name
            });
        }
    },$(this).data( 'pid' ).toString()).done( function( r, e ){
        //
    });

    /** setting the options has changed **/
    $(this).editable('option', 'source', arr);
    $(this).editable('option', 'success', function(response, newValue) {
        console.log($(this).data('pk'), newValue);
    });
});
```

you will notice that setting the options for editable has changed, setting the source this way:

```
$('.editable').editable({
    validate: function() {...}),
    success: function() {...}),
    source: function() {
        return arr;
    }
});
```

didn't work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

From the jquery-indexeddb documentation, I gather that its promises have `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.progress()` methods but, amazingly, not `.then()`.

This means that jquery-indexeddb's promises don't have the filtering ability afforded by `.then()` and (unless there's some unfathomable feature of indexedDB) it would be impossible to return a promise of the required array. Therefore we have to write what would normally be classed as the "deferred antipattern".

`popSelectBox()` will be something like this :

```
function popSelectBox(PID) {
    var arr = [],
        dfrd = jQuery.Deferred();
    $.indexedDB('testDatabase').objectStore('Lookup').index('PID').each(function(i) {
        arr.push({
            value: i.value.ID,
            text: i.value.Name
        });
    }, PID).done(function() { // not too sure about `PID` here
        dfrd.resolve(arr);
    }).fail(dfrd.reject);
    return dfrd.promise();
}
```

In the `.editable(...)` plugin, if the `source` option is a function then it must return the value (an array) *promised* by `popSelectBox()`, but importantly, it can't return the promise itself. Therefore, the essential feature of the pattern sought in `makeEditable()`, is that (for select elements) `popSelectBox()` be called first then `.editable(...)` called in response to the returned promise's resolution.

This effectively turns the current code in `makeEditable()` inside-out, with :

- outermost: the test of whether each element is a `<select>` and, when appropriate, a call to `popSelectBox()`.
- innermost: the call to `.editable()`.

The code could be written in a number of ways, the simplest of which (IMHO) is something like this :

```
function makeEditable() {
    var promises = $('.editable').map(function() {
        var $that = $(this),
            promise;
        if ($that.data('type') === 'select') {
            promise = popSelectBox($that.data('pid').toString());
        } else {
            promise = $.when(); //dummy, ready-resolved promise.
        }
        return promise.then(function(arr) {
            $('.editable').editable({
                validate: function() {...}),
                success: function() {...}),
                source: function() {
                    return arr || null; //assume it's safe to return null here for elements that are not selects.
                }
            });
        });
    });
    return $.when.apply(null, promises); //return a promise that will be resolved when all '.editable' elements have been initialized.
}
```

By returning a promise of completion, the function that calls `makeEditable()` can, if necessary, do something when all the elements have been made editable.

Comment: Hi this is great thanks, it is returning what we want, however it is not populating the select box.
Having put a few consoles around to see what is happening, it appears that arr is not in the scope of .editable functionality which is strange.
I'm not quite sure what it is doing but adding a console in the source function doesn't return anything until I click the element, then returns undefined. Adding a console above or below the .editable functionality returns what we expect

The PID in popSelectBox function is indexedDB functionality that we have, it acts like a where statement in sql

Comment: Is `popSelectBox` ever called, and does its promise get resolved?

Comment: "doesn't return anything until I click the element, then returns undefined" is worrying. How is `makeEditable()` called?

Comment: all fields that we want to be editable do become editable. `popSelectBox` is called and the state is resolved at the bottom of the function, meaning that it does pass into `return promise.when...` as resolved, arr also being passed here and has the values we expect, so the code works perfectly in that sense.
I have started looking into issues with x-editable and it appears it could be a problem with the source option itself, I have left a question on their page, I will leave this open until I find out more

Comment: The X-editable documentation indicates that the `source` option can be an array, so you might try `source: arr || null`.

Comment: we had tried this but again it didn't work, we have tried a few different ways, however from looking at x-editable issues, it seems you can't use a function as you would usually intend, so we have gone with a different approach, thanks for your help, I would vote up, however I don't have the rep to yet

Comment: @KrisHarris, for future reference maybe you could post an answer of your own to show what was necessary to fix the issue. I guess you're busy but maybe you could find a few minutes.